# How can I force an element to be visible?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a Chrome extension that interacts with a Yahoo UI on the page. Through a series of events, an element in the DOM becomes invisible on the page.

- I cannot see the contents of the element anywhere in the viewport.
- I can still see the element in the DOM in the Elements panel of Chrome DevTools.
- Hovering over the element in the Elements panel does not highlight an element on the page.
- Right-clicking the element in the Elements panel and choosing "Scroll into view" does not scroll the page, regardless of my scroll position in the page.
- I have set the following CSS properties, but the element is still invisible:

```
outline: 10px blue !important;
width: 400px !important;
height: 300px !important;
z-index: 2147483647 !important;
position: fixed !important;
left: 300px !important;
top: 100px !important;
margin: 0px !important;
display: block !important;
visibility: visible !important;
background: green !important;
border: 10px !important;
padding: 10px !important;
text-align: center !important;
opacity: 1 !important;
```

What could be causing this behavior? Is there anything I can do to fight it?

Comment: What is the element?

Comment: In the inspector, what styles are actually applied to the element?

Comment: Is there a parent/ancestor element with "display:none" set?

Comment: `<style>`,`<script>`,`<link>`,`<head>`,`<title>`,`<meta>` are not supposed to be visible. So if you are struggling with one of those elements, don't bother.

Comment: One of the ancestors indeed had `display: none`, and I just missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a parent/ancestor element with "display:none" set in its style/CSS?